# How to select button with his class for some function

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In this two buttons, i want to do two functions for adding class:

button1 add 'yellow' class to `<p id="p1">Hello1</p>`

and

button2 add 'green' class to `<p id="p2">hello2</p>`

I tried something in a function bellow but i want to select the id of `<p>` instead of `p:first`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function addClass() {
jQuery('button').click(
    function() {
        jQuery('p:first').addClass('intro');
    });
});
```

```css
.yellow,
.intro {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: yellow;
}
.green {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">Hello1</p>
<p id="p2">hello2</p>
<p id="p3">hello3</p>

<button id="b1">Button1</button>
<button id="b2">Button2</button>
```

Last question: why the first function work and the second doesn't!

First:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function addClass() {
    jQuery('button').click(function() {
        jQuery('p:first').addClass('intro');
    });
});
```

Second:

```
jQuery(document).ready( //without function
    jQuery('button').click(function() {
            jQuery('p:first').addClass('intro');
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `jQuery('#p1')` instead of using`jQuery('p:first')`

2) You can't write something like this

```
  jQuery(document).ready( //without function
                        jQuery('button').click(
```

it's a wrong syntax

**Full working code should be like:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function addClass() {
  jQuery('#b1').click(function() {
    jQuery('#p1').addClass('yellow');
  });
  jQuery('#b2').click(function() {
    jQuery('#p2').addClass('green');
  });
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: yellow;
}
.green {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="p1">Hello1</p>
<p id="p2">hello2</p>
<p id="p3">hello3</p>

<button id="b1">Button1</button>
<button id="b2">Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the p1 or p2 using the provided jquery selectors
`$('#p1")` the prefix `#` means that you want to select the **id** p1 .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

***Syntax :***

Two syntaxes can be used:

```
$(document).ready(function)
```

The ready() method can only be used on the current document, so no selector is required:

```
$(function)
```

function is required , it Specifies the function to run after the document is loaded.

you can also use $ instead of jQuery they are the same.

It must have a function or you can pass a named function see the documentation for more https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: Thanks. And If i have class="p1" ? Instead the id

Comment: It's easy instead of using '**#**' as a prefix use ' **.** ' example `$('.p1');`

Comment: Thanks, i'll validate your response

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery('#p1')` to select by id.

The right syntax for jquery ready method is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Use the id selector `jQuery("#p1")`. Also, not sure that the intended behavior ... but the way you have it coded it will apply regardless of which button you click. You may wanna use id selector there too!

Answer (score 1):

```
function function_name(){
// code for function decleration
}
```

just declares a function so that you can use that later. For example if you have to do something more than once. To use function you have to call it

```
function_name();
```

In your first example (of your last question) you just declare function. To better understand you could try to add

```
<button id="test">call function</button>
```

to your html and

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   addClass();
});
```

inside `$(document).ready` and play around. Also would strongly suggest to read more on JS and jquery. W3 school would be a goog place for you to start.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('button')` will select all the buttons. What you want is to select a specific button. Since both buttons have IDs, select them by their IDs like this:

```
jQuery('#b1').click(function(){
    // logic for the the button that has the ID b1
});

jQuery('#b2').click(function(){
    // logic for the the button that has the ID b2
});
```